# html5 placeholder with jquery - javascript input value see placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that another part of our team uses jquery for some functions. When the jquery* files are called my javascript validation see the HTML5 Placeholders as value. If I take out the jquery everthign works fine.

For example if I have this:

```
!document.getElementById("company").value
```

With the jquery in the html file either in the header or in the body my JS does not see this as null or empty it see is with a value of the HTML5 Placeholder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.main.js"></script>
```

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Write question properly so other can answer and help you.

Comment: Add more code where you have used placeholders so we can understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a form with a `placeholder` attribute which works fine. In your code, using vanilla javascript, you're reading out the `value` attribute of fields of that form and it normally returns an empty string if that field is empty. But now, upon including jQuery, asking for the `value` attribute returns the `placeholder` text instead.

It sounds like a bug to me. Are you by any chance using IE?
This is not a solution, but a work around. What you can do is compare the value you get to the placeholder text. If it's equal, then you conclude that the field is still empty:

```
<input name="company" type="text" id="company" onFocus="changebrc('Company');" placeholder="Company Name"/>
```

`if (document.getElementById("company").value == "Company Name"){/*field is empty*/}`

This will not work if the user decides to enter the same text written in the placeholder, which is quite unlikely if proper placeholder text is used.

Comment: My code is not in jquery it is in javascript. But I will give length a try.

Comment: I tried length in my javascript it still show the length of the placeholder. If I take out the references to the jquery everything works fine. But the jquery is used for other parts of the page nothing to do with what I am doing.   BTW thank you very much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Here are some of the input fields.                                                                                                                                              <input name="company" type="text" id="company" onFocus="changebrc('Company');" placeholder="Company Name"/>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onFocus="changebrc('fname');" placeholder="First Name"/>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" onFocus="changebrc('lname');" placeholder="Last Name"/>

Comment: Javascript !document.getElementById("fname").value

Comment: Just to clarify, jQuery isn't a language by itself, but a library of javascript written in javascript. So if you're using jQuery, it still means you're using javascript. Anyway, I think I've misunderstood your question, until now hopefully. I will edit my answer in another attempt to answer you.

Comment: Not using IE I thought about checking if the value = placeholder but I would rather not if possible.